# "Remediating" state with Ansible, when there is an error in config file AND package is not installed

Tags: ansible, debian

My Ansible role enforces a desired state.  If smokeping is not installed, and/or my `Targets` are not configured in smokeping, it will correct this.  (I've simplified the role here).

```
- name: Install smokeping
  package:
    name:
      - smokeping
    state: present

- name: Configure smokeping Alerts
  copy:
    src: Alerts
    dest: /etc/smokeping/config.d/
  notify:
    - Reload smokeping
```

Except, it won't work if there is an error in Alerts AND smokeping has been removed.  In this case, smokeping will fail to install.  Is it possible to solve this case as well?

```
Unpacking smokeping (2.7.3-2) ...                                                                                                                     
Setting up smokeping (2.7.3-2) ...                                                                                                                    
apache2_invoke cgi: already enabled                                                                                                                   
apache2_invoke: Enable configuration smokeping                                                                                                        
Job for smokeping.service failed because the control process exited with error code.                                                                  
See "systemctl status smokeping.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.                                                                            
invoke-rc.d: initscript smokeping, action "restart" failed.                                                                                           
● smokeping.service - Latency Logging and Graphing System                                                                                             
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smokeping.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)                                                            
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-02-28 16:19:01 GMT; 11ms ago                                                                     
     Docs: man:smokeping(1)                                                                                                                           
           file:/usr/share/doc/smokeping/examples/systemd/slave_mode.conf
  Process: 7227 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smokeping --pid-dir=/run/smokeping (code=exited, status=25)                                                      
                                                                                                                                                     
Feb 28 16:19:00 silo systemd[1]: Starting Latency Logging and Graphing System...
Feb 28 16:19:01 silo smokeping[7227]: ERROR: /etc/smokeping/config.d/Alerts, line 2: put an email address or the name of a program here
Feb 28 16:19:01 silo systemd[1]: smokeping.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=25/n/a
Feb 28 16:19:01 silo systemd[1]: smokeping.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 28 16:19:01 silo systemd[1]: Failed to start Latency Logging and Graphing System.
dpkg: error processing package smokeping (--configure):
 installed smokeping package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (241-7~deb10u6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 smokeping
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Write the config file first, before you install smokeping.

If your configuration includes secrets, you need to be careful with permissions. (And maybe create the user & group `smokeping` first?)

It is not a problem that we have `notify: Reload smokeping` in the first task, before smokeping is installed.  Handlers run at the end, after all the tasks have run.